# If I know all the parameters of a distribution (mean, deviation, skewness, kurtosis,...) how do I calculate what quantile a certain data is at?

Tags: probability, distributions, quantiles

I have a game with levels. I am tracking the time (in seconds) each of my users took to complete a certain level.

What I want to accomplish is to show the user how their time compares to others (i.e. "Your time is better than 60.5%") by using the existing data that I have.

From the raw data, I've extracted a sample of 1000 that represent each 1000th quantile. Based off of this, I was able to determine the basic properties of the distribution.

Mean 90,47152847
Standard Error 1,951841119
Median 75
Mode 300
Standard Deviation 61,75348928
Sample Variance 3813,493439
Kurtosis 2,127713313
Skewness 1,449926474
Range 296
Minimum 4
Maximum 300
Sum 90562
Count 1001

Is there a way to determine what quartile a certain user time would represent, just by using the above descriptive statistics, and not using the quantiles that I already have?

Reason why I would like to avoid comparing user time to a huge table of 1000 numbers is to save space in the code. So I am hoping for some way to calculate what quantile a user is near/at by using least amout of numbers

Comment: I would rather suggest an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function.

Comment: Finding the quantile from the original data (or even from a subsample of 1000) would be straightforward and accurate. If the type of distribution is known, getting the quantile from estimated moments might be inaccurate, problematic if not known. // Exact 80th percentile of Norm(μ=100,σ=15) is $112.6243.$ 80th percentile of sample of 1000: `set.seed(811); x = rnorm(1000, 100, 15); quantile(x, .8)` is 112.9092. Estimating μ,σ from sample of 1000: `qnorm(.8, mean(x), sd(x))` gives 112.8742.

Comment: Method of moments estimators of parameters may be difficult or imprecise for non-normal data. // Bootstrap CIs for quantiles would be possible for samples of size 1000, but certainly neither easier nor better than saving the quantile of the original large sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "save space in the code"? Shouldn't you store player performance in a database and then query it when you need the quantile, so that it can change over time as players improve? In a gaming context, it doesn't have to be exact as long as the players cannot reproduce the computation (i.e. they don't have access to the actual times), but it has to seem "fair". Also, the summary statistics you have above, are those for the times, or did you first compute quantiles and then compute e.g. the mean of the quantiles?

Comment: Chris, I've computed all the mentioned descriptive statistics from the quantiles. Should I not have done that? It seems to me that doing the analysis on entire population vs just the 1000 quantiles would net me similar enough results.

Comment: Why would it? What theorem are you basing that on? This feels like premature optimization. Could you elaborate on why the straightforward solution of computing the rank on the full dataset isn't feasible? Or, if that's too slow, computing and storing percentiles on a schedule and interpolating the result when the rank is queried?